# Connect to wifi on book

Tags: wifi, boot, wpa-supplicant

I have a relatively fresh install of RetroPie that won't connect to wifi on boot. (I'm copying these configs by hand)

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
        ssid="mynetwork"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="mypassword"
}
```

I haven't touched the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

~I can connect to the network using the following command:~
this was true, but now isn't. I'm not sure what changed.

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -I wlan0 -D wext
```

Without the `wext` driver that command fails.

I'm tempted to put the above command in a bash script, but that seems tacky at best. (edit: hacky, not tacky, but that works too)

I realized that I hadn't pre-processed the passphrase with `wpa_passphrase`. After doing that I see the same behavior.

After the `wpa_supplicant` command I'm seeing this:

```
Failed to add supported operating classes IE
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
```

Comment: Is the SSID actually hidden?  The Pi boards have always had problems with hidden ids and I would unhide it.  It does not really add anything to security as part of the device logging on exchange sends the SSID in plain text !!!  Are you using a WiFi dongle or built in?

Comment: I suspect the WiFi dongle is to blame. It has been in a drawer for a few years, and it looks like it is leaking corrosion. I’ve ordered a new one and will update when I can

Comment: One of my earlier observations was correct, using the `wext` driver directly works. I don't understand why the boot system doesn't work though, because `wext` is still the fallback. I think I need to get more error log reports.

Comment: From a quick Google - WEXT sits on top of the standard drivers and provides functionality / access that a driver may not (some details from the creator https://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html) . Wonder what RetroPi does in the network stack?

Comment: I dumped retropie and am using regular Rasp Pi OS now. I thought it was a buggy installation of wpa_supplicant. Walking through the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh` file it looks like pi calls `wpa_supplicant -D nl802011, wext`, which would imply it tries the nl80 dirver first, then falls-back. I deleted the call to that drive in case it was failing in a way that didn't pass to wext. Still didn't work